# How do I add a new document to MongoDB if a findOne() doesn't return a document?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a function which queries a MongoDB database. I would like to have it so if a user (document) is not found in the database then a new user (document) is created. I can't seem to find out what findOne returns if there is no document found. How would I go about adding this functionality. Here is the function:

```
async function getUserData(_key){
const client = new MongoClient(mongoUri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
try{
    await client.connect();
    const collection = client.db("myDb").collection("myCollection");
    const query = {t_id: String(_key[0]), c_id: String(_key[1]), u_id: String(_key[2])};
    
    const data = await collection.findOne(query);
    const returnData = {
                            u_id: data.u_id, 
                            t_id: data.t_id,
                            c_id: data.c_id
                        };

    return returnData;
} finally {
    await client.close();   
}}
```

Comment: What's the use case here? If you are saying that you would create a new document if it is not found, this basically implies in the end you plan on using the data you are querying with to the DB. In that case use update with upsert = true.

Comment: "I can't seem to find out what findOne returns if there is no document found." Regardless of whether it is spelled out in the documentation or not, this can be checked in your dev env in 2 minutes or less, no? And as pointed out above, this kind of operation is usually called an upsert. Mongodb can do upserts.

Comment: Thanks both! Sergio ahh yes I was struggling to write a test for it but managed to implement one. For reference it just returns null.